# Vercel Redirect trailing and non trailing slash

Tags: vercel

In my vercel.json i want redirect both trailing and non trailing slash for certain URL

i tired doing

```
{
      "source": "/docs/api/graphql/dam/overview/:path(introduction\\/?.*)",
      "destination": "/developers/docs/apis/asset-management/overview",
      "permanent": true
}
```

So what i wanted it to do was if the user goes to
`/docs/api/graphql/dam/overview/introduction`
or
`/docs/api/graphql/dam/overview/introduction/`

it should redirect to
`/developers/docs/apis/asset-management/overview`

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution to handle this

```
{
      "source": "/docs/api/graphql/dam/overview/(introduction\\/?.*)",
      "destination": "/developers/docs/apis/asset-management/overview",
      "permanent": true
    }
```